# Descent datum for a line bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, descent

Let $\pi:C \to \mathbb P^1$ be a double cover branched at $r$ points. To understand the theory of descent better, I would like, if possible, to construct by hands the descent datum of a line bundle for this simple setting.

Formally, a descent datum is given by a pair $(L,\varphi)$, where $L$ is a line bundle on $C$ and an isomorphism $\varphi:p_1^*L \to p_2^*L$, where $p_1,p_2$ are natural projections from $C \times_{\mathbb P^1} C$. The last curve is the union of two copies of $C$ intersecting at the ramification points. I noticed also that the line bundle $L$ on $C$ given by divisor $D$ pullbacks in terms of these two copies to $p_1^*L = (D,D)$ and $p_2^*L = (D,i(D))$, where $i$ is the involution action. Then, given that $D$ is invariant under involution, I can obviously come up with some $\varphi$. But this is surely is incorrect as not every line bundle invariant under involution descends.

Where my reasoning is wrong? Is it possible to construct descent in this settings and see the image of Picard group of $\mathbb P^1$ in the Picard group of $C$?

Comment: The isomorphism has to satisfy a condition, namely that $p_{23}^*\phi\circ p_{12}^*\phi=p_{13}^*\phi$, where $p_{ij}: C\times C\times C\to C\times C$ are the projections...

Comment: The Picard group of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $\mathbb{Z}$, and the map to $\operatorname{Pic}(C)$ is induced by base change on divisors.